# Git thinks there is nothing to pull after reverts

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to re pull/merge some branches into my dev branch, after reverting them (numerous times) but git thinks that there are no changes to make and is already up to date, when it is not...

I have put myself in a situation that I don't know how to get out of:

*standing in dev branch the entire time, using 'git pull origin foo' for merging and using GitKraken for the reverts*

1. merge branch X into dev and push (causes an issue with my build process)
2. merge branch Y into dev and push (to see if issues persist with branch, but branch X already exists...)
3. revert branch Y
4. revert branch X
5. push these together in one go

*tries pulling/merging branches back again, but git pull says everything is up to date in dev*

Now, at this point, I am back where I started before the merge, in terms of actual changes, however when I tried to re merge/pull stuff back in (in a different order) git says its already up to date (when it 100% is not).

So then I do the following (which is pointless)...

6. revert the revert for branch X (step 4)
7. revert the revert for branch Y (step 3)
8. revert the original changes for branch Y (step 2)
9. revert the original changes for branch X (step 1)
10. push all at once

But the same issue persists now (and is nastier with all this in my history) and some other people have merged stuff into dev now as well.

In short, how can I get git to actually pull and pick up my merge changes after I reverted them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep saying it's not up-to-date; it 100% is.  You told git to merge the branches, and then to make new changes that undo everything from those branches.  That's an up-to-date state, because all of the commit IDs you're trying to merge in are already in the target branch.

If you revert a merge and then later want to redo the merge, you have two options:

1. Revert the revert commit.  This is generally easier but you may or may not like the history it produces.
2. Rewrite the branch in new commits (with new commit IDs) so that you can "fool" git into thinking it hasn't already merged them in.  `git rebase -f` can be useful here.

Comment: But I am failing to understand is that, I have reverted everything, so the merges no longer exist in the dev branch, however, when i try to do: git pull origin X into dev, I do not see that it is pulling in any of the code from that branch and says it's up to date. And regarding step 2, do you mean i need to amend all of my previous merges and reverts for related to these changes?

Comment: No, that's not how revert works.  Reverting does not remove anything from the branch; it *adds* changes to undo previous changes.  The merge is still there.